# Change the values in a df based on a specific manner

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df which has only 0 and 1 values. I want to convert the values of 1 to zero, and also change the (t) values before/and after the 1 (it can be one number
or be mulitple 1 beside each other)
to 1. For example, in this df I want to change the t=1 number of zero before 1 to 1 and change the 1 to zero.

Here is the df I have:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
{'Ids': {0: 4, 1: 5, 2: 1},
 'val1': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0},
 'val2': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 1},
 'val3': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1},
 'val4': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1},
 'val5': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0},
 'val6': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1},
 'val7': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 1},
 'val8': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1},
 'val9': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 0},
 'val10': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 0},
 'val11': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1},
 'val12': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1},
 'val13': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0}}
Ids     val1    val2    val3    val4    val5    val6    val7    val8    val9    val10   val11   val12   val13
0   4   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0
1   5   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   0
2   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   1   0
```

Here is the df that I want:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Ids'] = [4, 5, 1]
df['val1'] = [1, 0,1]
df['val2'] = [0, 1,0]
df['val3'] = [0, 0,0]
df['val4'] = [0, 0,0]
df['val5'] = [1, 0,1]
df['val6'] = [1, 1,0]
df['val7'] = [0, 1,0]
df['val8'] = [0, 0,0]
df['val9'] = [0, 0,1]
df['val10'] = [0, 1,1]
df['val11'] = [1, 0,0]
df['val12'] = [0, 1,0]
df['val13'] = [0, 0,1]
    Ids     val1    val2    val3    val4    val5    val6    val7    val8    val9    val10   val11   val12   val13
0   4   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
1   5   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0
2   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1
```

Can you please help me with that?

I tried to use a loop over rows and columns. It does not work and also it is not optimum. I am pretty sure pandas has a better way to control this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can try:

```py
vals = df.loc[:, 'val1':]

x = vals.shift(1, axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int)
y = vals.shift(-1, axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int)
df.loc[:, 'val1':] = (x | y) * ~vals.astype(bool)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Ids  val1  val2  val3  val4  val5  val6  val7  val8  val9  val10  val11  val12  val13
0    4     1     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0      0      1      0      0
1    5     0     1     0     0     0     1     1     0     0      1      0      1      0
2    1     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1      1      0      0      1
```

Comment: Thank you Andrej. I copied your code and the results for me is a dataframe contains only zero.

Comment: @HbNIWNIW make sure you have correct types in columns. Also post your dataframe as dict ([edit] your question and put there output of `df.to_dict()`)

Comment: @HbNIWNIW You've edited your question but all the values are zeros. I mean post the input dataframe as dict (the dataframe should contain the 0-1 values)

Comment: yes. Sorry. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually, I tried the different input and change the input to int, float, and etc. However, still I get a dataframe with only zero! Its to weird for me. You provide " make sure you have correct types in columns", what type of columns I should use here? Thanks

Comment: @HbNIWNIW The numbers should be 0-1 integers. You can debug your program. First, do `print(x)` (does `x` contains only 0-1 integers?), then do `print(y)`, then `print(x | y)` and as final step `~vals.astype(bool)`. Observe where the values become all zeros.

Comment: Thanks. From the first line, for x  I only get a df with zero and also same for y. I tried to change some parts of the code based on some help from chatgpt, but it does not work also.

Comment: @HbNIWNIW and what `print(vals)` says? It should have all 0-1 integers, nothing else.

Comment: It has val1, val2, and etc. And the numbers 0, 1.

Comment: @HbNIWNIW Sorry, I cannot help you further. You should investigate why `vals.shift(1, axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int)` turns the values to zero. You can update `pandas` version etc.